# Limit of an integral of a sequence of functions so that $f_n(x)=f(x^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have the continuous function $f: A\to B$ where $A=B=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x):=f(x^n).$ I want to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx$$

I was thinking about applying an interchange of the limit and integral, and evaluating $\lim f_n(x)$, but I know that $x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$. Is there something special I can say about a continuous function $f$ composed with a non-uniformly converging $x^n$.

Comment: This is _obviously_ wrong. For example if $f(x)=1$ then $f_n(x)=1$ for all $n$. What does the problem actually ask?

Comment: I'm confused. What happens if $f(x)\equiv 1$?

Comment: The limit should be $f(0)$ instead of $0$. And if you have heard of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, recall that uniform convergence is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be the function such that $g(1)=f(1)$ and $g(x)=f(0)$ if $x \in [0,1)$.

For all $x \in [0,1]$, you have $$f_n(x)=f(x^n) \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty} g(x)$$
so $(f_n)$ simply converges to $g$.

Moreover, $f$ is continuous, so $\max_{[0,1]} f$ exists, and obviously,
$$\forall n,x, |f_n(x)| \leq \max_{[0,1]} f$$

which is integrable, as a constant, on $[0,1]$.

So you can apply the dominated convergence theorem, that tells you that 
$$\int_0^1 f_n(x) \mathrm{dx} \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_0^1 g(x) \mathrm{dx} = f(0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in (0,1).$ Then

$$\tag 1 |\int_0^1 f(x^n)\,dx - f(0)| = |\int_0^1 (f(x^n)-f(0))\,dx| $$ $$\le \int_0^1 |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx = \int_0^a |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx + \int_a^1 |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx$$ $$ \le \sup_{x\in [0,a^n]} |f(x)-f(0)|\cdot a + 2(1-a).$$

Because $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $a^n\to 0,$ $\sup_{x\in [0,a^n]} |f(x)-f(0)|\cdot a \to 0.$ Thus the $\limsup_{n\to \infty}$ on the left of $(1)$ is $\le 2(1-a).$ Now let $a\to 1^-$ to see this $\limsup$ is $0.$ This is the desired result.